# Service Workers & Promises: Correct Response not returned

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

In a Service Worker, I am using the following code to test if an external JavaScript file takes longer than 500 ms to return. The code below is also using a Promise race condition to determine if the network is faster, or a timeout. If the timeout wins, then I expect to return a 408 response.

```
function timeout(delay) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          new Response('', {
              status: 408,
              statusText: 'Request timed out.'
          });
        }, delay);
    });
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    // Only fetch JavaScript files for now
    if (/\.js$/.test(event.request.url)) {
      event.respondWith(Promise.race([timeout(500), fetch(event.request.url)]));
    } else {
      event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
    }
});
```

I am testing this by throttling the network connection using dev tools and forcing it to take longer than the set 500ms.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

The timeout wins every time and logs to the console which is exactly what I would expect. However, it doesn't return a 408 as expected, instead it returns a 200. Any ideas?

You can see an example of this in action on Github at:
https://deanhume.github.io/Service-Workers-Fetch-Timeout/

and the source:

https://github.com/deanhume/Service-Workers-Fetch-Timeout/blob/gh-pages/service-worker.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to execute `event.respondWith` not inside the promise:

(didn't try this code, just doing it on the fly)

```
function timeout(delay) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          resolve(new Response('', {
              status: 408,
              statusText: 'Request timed out.'
          }));
        }, delay);
    });
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    // Only fetch JavaScript files for now
    if (/\.js$/.test(event.request.url)) {
      event.respondWith(Promise.race([timeout(500), fetch(event.request.url)]);
    } else {
      event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
    }
});
```

Also modified the `timeout` function to return a response, so the `Promise.race` will return a `Response` object.

Comment: Note that the `event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));` in the `else {}` clause is not needed. If you leave out a call to `event.respondWith()` then the normal network request/response flow will still take place, without any service worker involvement.